# Using files in an Azure Dev Ops Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

What other process can I use to store a JAR file that is being used in a pipeline? I don't want to store it in a repo. I was looking at using 'secure files within the library' and then use YAML to get the files down - although there is a 10mb limit on these files.

Looking for a place to store these Java JAR files for use within Azure Pipelines and also how would I get hold of them within YAML.

Using secure file seems quite simple, although there is a size issue. Also the solution does not need to be secure really.

Using secure files is simple YAML - like below:

```
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: caCertificate
  displayName: 'Download CA certificate'
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'myCACertificate.pem'

- script: |
    echo Installing $(caCertificate.secureFilePath) to the trusted CA directory...
    sudo chown root:root $(caCertificate.secureFilePath)
    sudo chmod a+r $(caCertificate.secureFilePath)
    sudo ln -s -t /etc/ssl/certs/ $(caCertificate.secureFilePath)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Azure storage account to store your files, please get start from [Create a storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-create?tabs=azure-portal).

Then, use [Azure File Copy task](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fpipelines%2Ftasks%2Fdeploy%2Fazure-file-copy%3Fview%3Dazure-devops&data=04%7C01%7Cv-shuqiji%40microsoft.com%7C07b579166caf4e03efce08d9fcf3cff8%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637818946358670305%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000&sdata=zqOys1NKM4%2Bhkh7wzEb2nvn8wGXBRGgYyGbgIOHGjRk%3D&reserved=0) to copy files to Azure storage blobs when run on Windows agents. Or you can run the [az storage blob upload](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fcli%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblob%3Fview%3Dazure-cli-latest%23az-storage-blob-upload&data=04%7C01%7Cv-shuqiji%40microsoft.com%7C07b579166caf4e03efce08d9fcf3cff8%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637818946358670305%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000&sdata=jXluUjtjGMdceNP8mzRjqjCXtH4x%2FOqbl8%2FnQcSj%2Fk4%3D&reserved=0) command as below in Azure CLI task when running on Linux, macOS, or Windows operating systems to upload files to a storage blob.

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'My subscription'
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: 'az storage blob upload --account-name MyStorageAccount --account-key 0000-0000 -f Path/* -c MyContainer -n NewBlob'
```

To use this file, you could download it to your target directory by using Azure CLI task with command [az storage blob download](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fcli%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblob%3Fview%3Dazure-cli-latest%23az-storage-blob-download&data=04%7C01%7Cv-shuqiji%40microsoft.com%7C07b579166caf4e03efce08d9fcf3cff8%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637818946358670305%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000&sdata=p0IOOBYpvt0wo5hDt7eBJWa5tdy%2FVz8EmGMeAsys5b8%3D&reserved=0).

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'My subscription'
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: 'az storage blob download --account-name MyStorageAccount --account-key 0000-0000 --container-name MyContainer --file Path/to/file --name MyBlob'
```